# WordPress / Avada Theme: How to globally change text block aligment to justify?

Tags: html

Each time I add a text block, i need to manually change the text alignment to justify. Is there any way to globally set justify alingment for default?

im looking in the text block options but i havent find the solution. someone knows how to do it?